# Error finding a range of values in an array

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

The program "reads" non negative integers and fills an array of MAX size 100 until it is filled or the user gives -1.Then, function range finds the min and max values and "sends" them to the program.For example,if the user gives 67 54 78 85 -1 the range of values is 54-85.

Problem is, main doesn't print the range.  Instead, it prints: "The range of values is 2 - 24576000"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "simpio.h"

int read_data(int A[]);
void range(int sum,int A[100], int *r1, int *r2);

int main()
{
    int A[100], sum, max, min,i;
    int *r1,*r2;

    r1 = &max;
    r2 = &min;
    printf("Enter the elements of the array, one per line.\n");
    printf("Use -1 to signal the end of the list.\n");
    sum=read_data(A);
    range(sum,A, &max, &min);
    printf("The number of elements is: %d\n",sum);
    printf("The range of values is %d - %d",min ,max);

}

int read_data(int A[])
{
    int i,sum,value;

    sum=value=i=0;
    while ( i<100 && value !=-1)
    {
        printf("? ");
        value = GetInteger();
        if (value != -1)
            {
                A[i] = value;
                value = A[i];
                sum+=1;
            }
i++;

    }
    return sum;
}

void range(int sum,int A[100], int *r1, int *r2)
{
    int i,max,min;
    max =0;
    min = 32767;
    *r1 = min;
    *r2 = max;


    for(i=0;i<sum;i++)
    {
        if (A[i]!=-1)
        {
            if (A[i]>max)
                max = A[i];
            if (A[i]<min)
                min = A[i];
        }
    }
    *r1 = max;
    *r2 = min;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: "Problem is,it returns the value adress"  What does this mean?  What returns a pointer?  Certainly not the sum function, which is the only function that returns besides main.

Comment: To add clarity, please re-state the problem as a _question_.

Comment: @chux I suspect that read_data is returning some huge int that the OP thinks is a pointer, but i dont want to have to guess what hes asking.  "read_data" is the only function that returns and it returns an int "sum" which is not a pointer.

Comment: My mistake.English is not my native language so the terminology gives me a hard time.As far as i know,functions do not "receive" the actual array but a copy of its adress.I guess this is why the program doesnt print the actual range of the elements.

Comment: Note: `int *r1,*r2;

    r1 = &max;
    r2 = &min;` in `main()` serve no purpose, except to distract.

Comment: "67,54,78,85,-1" may not work as input.  Try again without commas `,`.  Post the _exact_ text used.

Comment: Thanks!That was actually the mistake.I didnt use commas in the program.But  int *r1,*r2; r1 = &max; r2 = &min; was causing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

One of the problems is that you are not incrementing the value of i in function read_data.

The other problem is that the 4th printf

> printf("%The number of elements is: %d\n",sum);

in the function main has a "%T" which is considered by the printf function to be a format specifier(like the one you use for the integer "%d"). If you really want to write % there you should use the format

> printf("%%The number of elements is: %d\n",sum);

and it will print only one %.

If you would like to know more about the format specifiers accepted by printf http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/ .